# String iteration using each_line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code which displays instructions in an ordered list. When it's rendered in the browser, it outputs all of the instructions at the end in a single line. Am I doing something wrong? See output below for example.

Code:

```
 <% @recipe.instructions.each_line do |instruction| %>
  <li><%= instruction %></li>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<p>
  <b>Instructions:</b>
  <ol>
      <li>Roast garlic
</li>
      <li>test
</li>
      <li>eat icecream</li>
Roast garlic
test
eat icecream  </ol>
</p>
```

Rails 3 rc2 ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-11 revision 28618)

Comment: Can you share the code above & below this?  I have a feeling that there might be some temporary debug code lurking...

Comment: Actually you can see all the code, here's the page in question http://github.com/quattro004/scratches/blob/master/app/views/recipes/show.html.erb see around line 46 - 53.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you aren't doing something like this instead?

```
<%= @recipe.instructions.each_line do |instruction| %>
  <li><%= instruction %></li>
<% end %>
```

Note the extra = at the beginning of the loop.  Since each_line returns the string, it'll spit the string out again.

Comment: Actually I was getting the following deprecation warning on that line (DEPRECATION WARNING: <% %> style block helpers are deprecated. Please use <%= %>), so I added the = and the warning goes away but the output is still the same.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I really don't think <% %> has been deprecated.  <%- %> may have been.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out. I changed the code to use Array#each and removed the equal sign in the block helper.

Final code:

```
<% @recipe.instructions.split(/\r\n/).each do |instruction| %>
  <li><%= instruction %></li>
<% end %>
```